# C# How to notify a class (simple true/false) when a static method in another class has been invoked?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

- Question:

  How do I notify/update my winform when ping has ran(which would change my hypothetical send indicator)?
- Scenario:

  Say I have thread that is off sending pings to a computer. while the main thread is showing/in charge of the winform gui - completely separate classes.

  1. I have a **WinForm** that shows two little status indicators(Send & Receive)
  2. I have a class `B` that has a static method `Ping()`
  3. I have a thread spawn that continually runs `Ping()`

Comment: Sounds like a good job for [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx)

Comment: @Bort I'm a java programmer so these concepts are new to me. Could you elaborate on how that would work. Thanks greatly

Comment: I found reading [.NET Delegates: A C# Bedtime Story](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/writing/delegates.htm) to be useful when I first learned about events.

Answer (score 1):

you would be best using "events", have a look at the example code that microsoft provide, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I'm sure it sounds trivial but do/can these events happen globally?

Comment: any class can register to listen for the events as long as the event is public and/or static

Answer (score 0):

As most people here have suggested used events to do that.

```
public partial class Form1: Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Sample sample=new Sample();
        sample.SampleEvent+=sample_SampleEvent;
        sample.SampleMethod();
    }

    private void sample_SampleEvent() {
        Console.WriteLine("SampleMethod has been executed and the method on the WinForm has been notified about it.");
    }
}

public class Sample {
    public event SampleEventHandle SampleEvent;
    protected virtual void OnSampleEvent() {
        var handler=SampleEvent;
        if(handler!=null)
            handler();
    }

    public delegate void SampleEventHandle();


    public void SampleMethod() {
        OnSampleEvent();
    }
}
```